# Como mostrar resultados da table sempre no topo?

Tags: php, html

Estou montando um chat e ocorreu que as mensagens estão aparecendo no final da table, de baixo pra cima.
Ou seja, tenho que descer o scroll para ver as novas mensagens. E eu gostaria de ver as mensagens no topo.

Já peguei alguns exemplos de chat e a mensagem aparece sempre em cima, mas não lembro como é feito.

Alguém pode dar uma força nisso?

Comment: E como você insere a mensagem na conversa? Um novo div com JavaScript puro ou talvez framework? Ou carrega a página toda novamente? Como o navegador cliente sabe que deve carregar novas mensagens? Verifica periodicamente?

Comment: Long Polling é responsável pelo carregamento dinâmico das conversas. A mensagem é inserida via javascript puro mesmo.